# AWS: OverflowError when downloading file from s3 to lambda tmp folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to download file from a s3 and save it into the tmp folder of my lambda. But I accountered a stange and unexpected error that makes me crazy: **OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t**

Here is my code, did I miss something?

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
keys = ['private.pkcs8', 'public.pubkey']
for key in keys: 
    try:
        local_file_name = 'tmp/' + key
        s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key, local_file_name)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
      if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
          continue
      else:
          raise
```

I have the same error when retrieving s3 as Client and not Resource.
With different log, I could check the error comes with the "download_file" function.

Please, help me!!!

EDIT: the full stack trace of the error

> 14:04:36
>   [ERROR] 2020-02-18T14:04:36.104Z f8f5aef0-18a3-41d0-951f-4d979fb24aa4 timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t
>   14:04:36
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
>   14:04:36
>   extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
>   
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
>   14:04:36
>   future.result()
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
>   14:04:36
>   return self._coordinator.result()
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
>   14:04:36
>   raise self._exception
>   
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
>   14:04:36
>   self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/download.py", line 343, in _submit
>   14:04:36
>   **transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 276, in _api_call
>   14:04:36
>   return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
>   14:04:36
>   raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>   14:04:36
>   botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
>   14:04:36
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   14:04:36
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   14:04:36
>   File "/var/task/lb_get_tlb_connection_token_rds.py", line 181, in lambda_handler
>   14:04:36
>   bucket.download_file(key, local_file_name, ExtraArgs={'VersionId': 'foo'})
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 246, in bucket_download_file
>   14:04:36
>   ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
>   14:04:36
>   extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
>   
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 325, in **exit**
>   14:04:36
>   self._manager.**exit**(*args)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/manager.py", line 539, in **exit**
>   14:04:36
>   self._shutdown(cancel, cancel_msg, cancel_exc_type)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/manager.py", line 578, in _shutdown
>   14:04:36
>   self._submission_executor.shutdown()
>   
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/s3transfer/futures.py", line 474, in shutdown
>   14:04:36
>   self._executor.shutdown(wait)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/opt/python/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 169, in shutdown
>   14:04:36
>   t.join(sys.maxsize)
>   14:04:36
>   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1048, in join
>   14:04:36
>   self._wait_for_tstate_lock(timeout=max(timeout, 0))
>   14:04:36
>   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>   14:04:36
>   elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
>   14:04:36
>   OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t

Comment: Is your file size exceeds 500MB? Then it would fail.

Comment: no, it's a tiny private or public key, less than 2ko

Answer (score 0):

This looks like runtime problem, probably related to this bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue25155

Try changing your lambda runtime to the latest supported (Python 3.8 as of time of writing) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I've already seen this link but as my python version is 3.7, it should work

Comment: @Turvy I would still try 3.8 and also, as a debugging measure, try launching same code in other region, to see if this is really code or runtime.

Comment: I'm just change the runtime of the lambda, and I've still the error

Comment: @Turvy can you add full traceback for the error then?

Comment: see the edit, I hope you could understand something

Comment: @Turvy do you configure connection timeout in any way, like creating `Config` object? Because what I can google is that it gets timeout parameter passed to underlying threading lib, and that number is too big for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I could contact the support center of AWS, and they try to solve the problem. My function works well locally or as CLI command

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. It came from a library in our layer which conflict with boto3